# Add one page scroll to already existing template

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, scroll

I'm working on my first bootstrap website and yes, I'm a noob. After a long journey, I found [this](http://ironsummitmedia.github.io/startbootstrap-stylish-portfolio/) template to work with.
At the end of the day, it will contain over 20 fullpage sections like the header with texts, images, videos and audios. 
This template has a scrolling script:

```
// Scrolls to the selected menu item on the page
$(function() {
    $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
        if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') || location.hostname == this.hostname) {

            var target = $(this.hash);
            target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
            if (target.length) {
                $('html,body').animate({
                    scrollTop: target.offset().top
                }, 1000);
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Now, here is the special price question. There is this 'one page scroll' by [Pete Design](http://www.thepetedesign.com/demos/purejs_onepage_scroll_demo.html). This contains a template-css and js-file. 
Is it possible to mix these two templates?

I like to add the Pete Design JS-Template to add:
scrolling section by section with the mousewheel/keyboard arrows and the swipe-function but I want/like to use the design (espacially navbar!) from Startbootstrap.

Comment: I doubt it will be that simple. The one page scroller uses its own element for creating "page" sections, which differs from what bootstrap is doing. You either have to use the onePageScroller and do your own design, or in bootstrap measure the height of "page" and do a function onclick, go down this height. And just duplicate mousewheel and swiping.

Comment: Thanks @Alexey for the quick reply! Honstly, I have no clue of javescript so I would have to post the code and ask for help. But before I do that: I would have to set the hight of every section to max. 100%, right? And everything what does not fit into the hight would be cut of, right? That would make it really complicate for mobile phones. Is there an other option like when I scroll from section a to section b, that will fix the upcomming section at the top of the window? (hope you or others understand what I mean :/ )

Comment: OnePageScroll is not very good with mobile, I can tell you that right away.